# Detect and control the creation of self-closing xml elements in Python?

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

Maybe I overlooked but I didn't find this in the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html).

When parsing an xml in Python's ElementTree, how can I detect if a element|tag|node is `self-closing` (or unpaired, ie. ending with `/>`) or not?

When creating xml files, how can I explicitly state if I'm for a `self-closing` (`/>`) or an `explicitly closed` (ie. `</example>`) xml tag?

In case ElementTree does not, does other python parsers handle this better?

Comment: XML does not give you the distinction; `<tag></tag>` and `<tag />` are equivalent. Thus ElementTree cannot give you the same information. See http://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#IDAHKIS on the subject of empty elements.

Comment: @MartijnPieters +1 that's nice, but there is also quirk-mode and document types. While going with the standard is perfectly valid approach, I still like being in control. Doing it 'right' requires learning and so it's just less error-prone if one could produce exactly what he wants, compared to going with a random result due to "giving up" because of one's frustration. (Not speaking of myself here :P but I think this is important.)

Comment: Quirks-mode applies to how *browsers* interpret *HTML*. ElementTree is not a HTML parser, it's a XML parser, and it takes a strict interpretation of the data. The ElementTree's aim is to provide a simple API, and basically ignores the DTD for most purposes. The spec only states that a DTD declaration of `EMPTY` SHOULD result in the empty element tag form being used, but a SHOULD means that a tool like ElementTree can get away with ignoring that.

Comment: But you may want to look into [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/); it builds on the ElementTree API and does also include validation tools; perhaps that API gives you more control over empty vs. no content tags.

Comment: @MartijnPieters thanks :) by the way, I was talking about producing xhtml for browsers with quirks mode. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 5):

This issue was addressed in March 2014 by python 3.4. It added the [`short_empty_elements`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.tostring) argument to all serialization functions of `ElementTree`.

```
>>> from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
>>> msg = ET.Element('msg',{'x': 'y'})
>>> ET.tostring(msg)
b'<msg x="y" />'
>>> ET.tostring(msg, short_empty_elements=False)
b'<msg x="y"></msg>'
```